# Assigning different labels dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

After detecting Button sender through its tag in an action method, I want to dynamically assign some text to the corresponding Label (say, button tag+10 ) using some sort of temp UILabel var.

Hoping that's understandable?..english is not my native language :)

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the containing view, you can use viewWithTag to get the object with a specific tag.

If you know the object is a UILabel, you can typecast it to get your label object.

If you are in your viewcontroller.m file:

```
UILabel* myLabel;

myLabel = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:(buttonTag+10)];
```

Good luck!

Comment: Swiftly and sharply answered. Working already. Thank you Rob.

Comment: Glad to help. Stack Overflow gives me extra points if you mark this answer as your accepted answer. Just click the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!